# Summing numbers from list with spaces in Python

Tags: python, list

For a homework assignment we have to create a .txt file containing 10 lines of 2 numbers, each number separated by a space, e.g. 1 9. Then create a program which can open the file, read the numbers into a list, convert the list to integers, sum the integers, and then save the sum to a new file.

I got it to open the file, and add the data into a list splitting off the \n at the end of each line in the file, but the list still contains spaces so I can't sum it. How do I get rid of the spaces? Here's my code so far.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


def main():
    # Introduce program to the user.
    print("This program allows you to open a text (.txt) file, read it's\n"
          "data into a list, sum the data, and save it as a new file.\n")

    # Open file
    infileName = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(infileName, "r")

    # read data into a list
    numbers = []
    for line in infile:
        line = infile.read()[:-1].split("\n")
        numbers.append(line)
    infile.close()

    print(numbers)

    # Convert list str to int
    numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
    print(numbers)
    # total = 0

    # Save file
    outfilename = asksaveasfilename()
    outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

    # Close outfile
    outfile.close()


main()
```

This is the output I get back when running it.

```
D:\Users\brumm\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hw5project2\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Users/brumm/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/hw5project2/main.py
This program allows you to open a text (.txt) file, read it's
data into a list, sum the data, and save it as a new file.

[['0 2', '2 4', '1 9', '7 5', '6 4', '0 8', '9 4', '1 2', '4 1']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\brumm\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hw5project2\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Users\brumm\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hw5project2\main.py", line 44, in main
    numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
  File "D:\Users\brumm\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hw5project2\main.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help, I'm stuck.

Comment: Sum by line or sum all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several problems in your code

- You don't use the iterated `line` and use `infile.read()` that reads the **whole** file at once, so there is only one iteration, and one value set in the array. You'd need someting like that

  ```
  numbers = []
  for line in infile:
      row_values = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
      numbers.extend(row_values)
  ```
- you don't split each line, so you try to convert strings like `'7 8'` as one `int` that isn't possible
- better use files with `with` statement, it autocloses them

---

The loop for reading is nice, but with your input format there is a better solution : `str.split()` without any parameter, it'll split on any amonut of whitespace, newlines included. So it can saparate each int, from each line at once

```
infile.read().split() # ['0', '1', '2', '4', '3', '8', '7', '8', '5', '6', '6', '7']
numbers = [int(i) for i in infile.read().split()]
# [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 8, 5, 6, 6, 7]
```

---

Giving something like :

```
infileName = "test.txt"
with open(infileName, "r") as infile:
    numbers = [int(i) for i in infile.read().split()]


print(numbers)
total = sum(numbers)

outfilename = "out.txt"
with open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(total))
```

---

A very condensed version, with the files open at the same place would be

```
infileName, outfilename = "test.txt", "out.txt"
with open(infileName, "r") as infile, open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(sum(map(int, infile.read().split()))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what you mean about my code. I'm taking python programming in school and I was using the methods taught in the book so far, which is rudimentary at best, but that's the nature of institutional education lol.

Comment: @JamesBrummett You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Comment: I tried upvoting, but I need more reputation. I used a little of what you did and a little of the what Jitesh did below to complete the project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code assuming you want to sum all the elements from the list.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename


def main():
    # Introduce program to the user.
    print("This program allows you to open a text (.txt) file, read it's\n"
          "data into a list, sum the data, and save it as a new file.\n")

    # Open file
    infileName = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(infileName, "r")

    # read data into a list
    numbers = []
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
        line = line.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        numbers.append(int(line))  # Convert list str to int
    infile.close()

    print(numbers)
    sum_numbers = sum(numbers)
    print(sum_numbers)


    # Save file
    outfilename = asksaveasfilename()
    outfile = open(outfilename, "w")
    outfile.write(str(sum_numbers))
    
    # Close outfile
    outfile.close()


main()
```

### Explanation

1. To remove space between two numbers, we use replace method. Here we removed unwanted characters to smoothly convert to int in the next step.

   ```
       line = line.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
   ```
2. Here we convert the number from string to integer and appended it to the list.

   ```
       numbers.append(int(line))  # Convert list str to int
   ```
3. Here we added all the elements from the list.

   ```
   sum_numbers = sum(numbers)
   ```
4. Here we are writing the sum of all elements of the list into a new file. Since we can only write strings in the file, we converted it into a string first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I used a little of what you did and a little of what azro did above to compete the project.